# Overriding an object in memory with placement new

Tags: c++, placement-new

I have an object which I want to 'transform' into another object. For this I am using a `placement new` on the first object which creates a new object of the other type on top of its own address.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Animal {
public:
  virtual void voice() = 0;
  virtual void transform(void *animal) = 0;
  virtual ~Animal() = default;;
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
  std::string name = "CAT";
  void voice() override {
    std::cout << "MEOW I am a " << name << std::endl;
  }
  void transform(void *animal) override {
  }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
  std::string name = "DOG";
  void voice() override {
    std::cout << "WOOF I am a " << name << std::endl;
  }
  void transform(void *animal) override {
    new(animal) Cat();
  }
};
```

You can see that when a `Dog` is called with `transform` it creates a new `Cat` on top of the given address.
Next, I will call the `Dog::transform` with its own address:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Animals.h"

int main() {
  Cat cat{};
  Dog dog{};
  std::cout << "Cat says: ";
  cat.voice() ;
  std::cout << "Dog says: ";
  dog.voice();
  dog.transform(&dog);
  std::cout << "Dog says: ";
  dog.voice();
  std::cout << "Dog address says: ";
  (&dog)->voice();
  return 0;
}
```

The results of this is:

```
Cat says: MEOW I am a CAT
Dog says: WOOF I am a DOG
Dog says: WOOF I am a CAT
Dog address says: MEOW I am a CAT
```

My questions are:

1. Is this operation considered safe, or does it leave the object in unstable state?
2. After the transform I call `dog.voice()`. It correctly prints the name `CAT` (it is now a cat), but still writes `WOOF I am a`, even though I would have thought that it should call the `Cat`'s `voice` method? (You can see is that I call the same method but by the address (`(&dog)->voice()`), everything is working properly.

Comment: I can't cite where in the standard it says that this isn't allowed, but I can say that I get "WOOF I am a CAT" in both of the bottom lines on my system, which is a pretty good indicator that this behavior is not portable.

Comment: If you need this behavior which I would describe as "The object will appear to change it's class", consider using the Gang of Four State Pattern:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Answer (score 15):

> Does this operation considered safe, or does it leave the object in unstable state?

This operation is not safe and causes undefined behavior.  `Cat` and `Dog` have non trivial destructors so before you can reuse the storage `cat` and `dog` have you have to call their destructor so the previous object is cleaned up correctly.

> After the transform I call `dog.voice()`. I prints correctly the `CAT` name (it is now a cat), but still writes `WOOF I am a`, even tough I would have thought that it should call the `Cat`'s `voice` method? (You can see is that I call the same method but by the address (`(&dog)->voice()`), everything is working properly.

Using `dog.voice();` after `dog.transform(&dog);` is undefined behavior.  Since you've reused its storage without destroying it, you have undefined behavior.  Lets  say you do destroy `dog` in `transform` to get rid of that bit of undefined behavior you still aren't out of the woods.  Using `dog` after it has been destroyed is undefined behavior.  What you would have to do is capture the pointer placement new returns and use that pointer from then on.  You could also use `std::launder` on `dog` with a `reinterpret_cast` to the type you transformed it to but it's not worth since you lose all encapsulation.

---

You also need to make sure when using placement new that the object you are using is large enough for the object you are constructing.  In this case it should be since the classes are the same but a `static_assert` comparing the sizes will guarantee that and stop the compilation if it is not true.

---

One way you can fix this is to create a different animal class that acts as a holder of your animal class (I renamed it to `Animal_Base` in the sample code below).  This lets you encapsulate the changing of what type of object an `Animal` represents.  Changing your code to

```
class Animal_Base {
public:
  virtual void voice() = 0;
  virtual ~Animal_Base() = default;
};

class Cat : public Animal_Base {
public:
  std::string name = "CAT";
  void voice() override {
    std::cout << "MEOW I am a " << name << std::endl;
  }
};

class Dog : public Animal_Base {
public:
  std::string name = "DOG";
  void voice() override {
    std::cout << "WOOF I am a " << name << std::endl;
  }
};

class Animal
{
    std::unique_ptr<Animal_Base> animal;
public:
    void voice() { animal->voice(); }
    // ask for a T, make sure it is a derived class of Animal_Base, reset pointer to T's type
    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Animal_Base, T>, bool> = true>
    void transform() { animal = std::make_unique<T>(); }
    // Use this to say what type of animal you want it to represent.  Doing this instead of making
    // Animal a temaplte so you can store Animals in an array
    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Animal_Base, T>, bool> = true>
    Animal(T&& a) : animal(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<T>(a))) {}
};
```

and then adjusting `main` to

```
int main() 
{
    Animal cat{Cat{}};
    Animal dog{Dog{}};
    std::cout << "Cat says: ";
    cat.voice() ;
    std::cout << "Dog says: ";
    dog.voice();
    dog.transform<Cat>();
    std::cout << "Dog says: ";
    dog.voice();
    std::cout << "Dog address says: ";
    (&dog)->voice();
    return 0;
}
```

produces the output

```
Cat says: MEOW I am a CAT
Dog says: WOOF I am a DOG
Dog says: MEOW I am a CAT
Dog address says: MEOW I am a CAT
```

and this is safe and portable.

Comment: Very well said, and +1 for pointing out more esoteric options like `std::launder`. The only thing I would add is a recommendation to use standard polymorphism instead of... whatever you call `transform()`.

Comment: @Kevin I was thinking about it an decided to do one better an have added an example of how the OP can get the behavior they are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

1) No, this is not safe for the following reasons:

- The behavior is undefined and can be different for some compilers.
- The allocated memory needs to be big enough to hold the newly created structure.
- Some compilers might call the destructor of the original object even if it is virtual, which would lead to leaks and crashes.
- In your code, the destructor of the original object is not called, so it can lead to memory leaks.

2) I observed on MSVC2015 that `dog.voice()` will call `Dog::voice` without checking the actual virtual table. In the second case, it checks the virtual table, which has been modified to be `Cat::voice`. However, as experienced by other users, some other compiler might perform some optimizations and directly call the method that matches the declaration in all cases.

Comment: When you say behavior is not portable you need to explain why. The destructor is already virtual.

Comment: I meant that some compilers do not behave the same. "Undefined behavior" might be better. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Do note there is a virtual destructor in the code in question

Comment: @NathanOliver That's true. I was mentioning general rules that needs to be respected. I will make it clearer.

Answer (score 6):

You have at least three issues with this code:

- There is no guarantee that when placement new is called the size of the object you are constructing your new object in is sufficient to hold the new object
- You are not calling destructor of the object used as a placeholder
- You use the `Dog` object after it's storage has been reused.